# Select lines in Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to be able to select one out of two lines to compare with. My function needs to be able to take two inputs in a two row textarea and then say "go" if the first line is longer than the other and "no" if the second line is longer
than the first.

I cannot get it to work with my jQuery and I don't know how to select each line and compare them.

```js
var lines = $('#input').val().split('\n');

// Loop through all lines
for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
  console.log('Line ' + j + ' is ' + lines[j])
}

let marius = input();
let doctor = inputArray();
let go = "go";
let no = "no";

$('#run').click(function) {
  if (marius.length > doctor.length)
    $("#output").val(go);
  else
    print("go");
  $("#output").val(no);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="input" rows=2></textarea><br>
<textarea id="output" rows=2></textarea><br>
<button id='run'>Run code!</button>
```

Comment: Your JS code has some syntax issues and missing code (ie. the `input` and `inputArray` functions). Please edit the question to include all relevant code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well that shouldn't be needed? I have tried to use a loop to count each line but it doesn't work for me. I am trying to use Jquery in this case to just compare lines of text, if one is longer than the other, and give an answer in the second "output" box.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, im going to re-do everything and try by myself from scratches to understand everything. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, read comments in the code

```js
// only run code when "run" has been clicked
$('#run').on('click', function(){
    var lines = $('#input').val().split('\n');

    if(lines.length <= 1) {
        return; // stop here! we don't have two lines to compare!
    }

    if(lines[0].length < lines[1].length) {
        $('#output').val('no');
    } else {
        $('#output').val('go');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input" rows=2></textarea>
<br>
<textarea id="output" rows=2></textarea>
<br>
<button id='run'>Run code!</button>
```

Comment: Yeah it works! Thanks, i have read thru the comments and trying to understand this better,

Comment: @MrLowBot add `console.log()` everywhere where you don't understand something. like before the `if(..)` statements do : `console.log(lines)` or even `console.log(lines, 'length: ' + lines.length)` and so on